# Can somebody provide a simple C# coding example for capturing SharePoint details for a single file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

I am working with VS 2008 and am able to apply the Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL file as a reference in the code.  There are many examples avaialble for batch processing files in entire SharePoint folders, but I am looking for a simple in C# example for capturing the following properties given the following for a single file on SharePoint.

Given the following:
- URL folder path ("http://community.xx.com/yada/blah/AllItems.aspx")
- FileName ("MyFile.xls")
- UNC ("\community.xx.com\yada\blah\MyFile.xls")

Results needed for following properties:
- Modified By
- TimeLastModified
- UniqueID
- FileType
- Title

I am guessing that SPFile and SPUser need to be applied, but am not clear as to how.

Thanks

Comment: So take one of the examples that "does it in batch". Then just remove the loops. Done. You'll only need to get the SPFile a different way - see SPWeb.Files, e.g. It will take a bit of fiddling to "normalize" those file names (e.g. get web relative path, which is close toe the 3rd example provided). If the goal is to find *any* "MyFile.xls" (across webs) then it'll be the same as the batch approach - e.g. search everything - but only process some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a lot easier than you think...

```
string fullItemUri = "http://community.xx.com/yada/blah/MyFile.xls";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(fullItemUri))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
   SPListItem item = web.GetListItem(fullItemUri);

   string modifiedBy = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified_x0020_By] as string;
   DateTime timeLastModified = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Last_x0020_Modified] as DateTime;
   int uniqueID = item.ID;
   string fileType = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileType] as string;
   string title = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] as string;
}
```

See the MSDN Article for [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid_members.aspx) and [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_members.aspx) for more.

Comment: Thanks Steve!  That answered my question exactly.